# Javadoc value of static byte in hex form

Tags: java, javadoc

I have some `static final byte` fields in a class:

```
public static final byte    TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL     = 0x0F;
public static final byte    TOP_CENTER_SIGNAL   = 0x1F;
public static final byte    TOP_RIGHT_SIGNAL    = 0x3F;
```

and I'm writing documentation for some class methods, like so:

```
/**
 * Takes a signal byte and returns an encoded message (byte array).
 * <p>
 * Example:
 * <pre>
 * Input - {@value #TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL} (TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL)
 *
 * Output - [0x00, 0x0F, 0x52, 0x53]
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param b
 *            - signal byte.
 * @return an encoded message (byte array).
 */
public static final byte[] encodeMsg(byte b) {
    return addTail(b);
}
```

The above documentation outputs the `Input - {@value #TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL} (TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL)` line like so:

```
Input - 15 (TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL)   // 15 is underlined and linked to the static variable
```

**My two questions:**

1. Is there a way to output the static value in hexadecimal format with
   a leading `0x` (`0x0F` instead of `15`)? Something like, `Input - {@value Integer#toHexString(Foo#TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL)}`
2. Can I make it so that the value (`15` in this example) is not
   underlined and not linked to the static field, while still using the value of the static field?

Are either of my questions possible?

**Reasoning:**

I'm currently putting the literal byte values (`0x0F`) in the documentation. The reason why I want to automate this is because this is a utility class that I have already written the methods for and some of the constants. As I write the core classes that make use of this utility class I find myself needing to add constants but not change the methods. The constants are separated into different byte blocks, like 0x40 - 0x4F and larger values are meant to carry a heavier meaning. Thus when I insert a new constant that carries a lesser weight than another constant, I insert the constant and shift the other constant values up. This makes me need to update every example in every method's documentation.

**Workaround to the first question:**

I know I could use the following workaround to answer the first question.

```
public static final String    TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL    = "0x0F";

/**
 * Input - {@value #TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL} (TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL)
 */
public static final byte[] encodeMsg(String b) {
    return addTail(Byte.decode(b));
}
```

But I'd rather not use `Byte.decode(String nm)` whenever I need the byte value of a static field.

Comment: **Why** do you want to use a constant, but not *link* your documentation to the constant at the same time? If the value is just an example, you may still write something like `Input - a suitable value, typically {@link #TOP_LEFT_SIGNAL}` or something like this. If your value `15` is not inherently connected with the constant, why not to put just the literal `0x0F` into your javadoc?

Comment: @HonzaZidek updated question to include reasoning, and updated javadoc.

Comment: Well-structured and well-formatted question about uncommon problem, with the OP displaying attempt and effort to solve the issue before asking. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your values are *constant*, maybe you can use `{@literal literal_text}`.

Or you can create your own `custom Javadoc tags` through a class extending `Doclet`, as described [in the Doclet documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer : ) - The values are constant in the run-time sense, however they are open to change pre-compilation. Also, it's simpler to put `0x0F` in the documentation instead of `{@literal 0x0F}`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Then I think you will have to create your own Javadoc `tag` through a `Doclet`, to deal with this specific scenario, and share that as part of the app. Unfortunately, that's unknown territory for me, so I can't do much more than point you to the official documentation on this. [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec/index.html) is the latest documentation I could find. And [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html#customtags) is an example of implementing your own Javadoc tags.

Comment: Scratch that. [Here's the latest doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/package-summary.html), although, it might say the same thing, just in more modern visuals.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know you could create your own Javadoc tags. Thanks for the information and I think creating a Javadoc tag would probably be the best approach, then I could use it in future situations.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Well, to tell you the truth, I didn't know either (hence why it is unknown territory to me), and I only thought about it (and subsequently found the docs, where I could confirm it) because it's common to be able to create your own tags in this kind of `generator` system. So yea, I guess we both learnt something. =P Anyways, glad I could help!

Comment: @Jonny did you actually try this approach? If it worked, it would be great if you would add another answer to your question with some code for copy&waste. I have the exact same problem.